# Python Raspberry PI Guessing Game(Function call not working)

Tags: python, input

My problem is that my Random function doesn't get called from the Menu function. I've tried everything, but it still doesn't work. It's weird, because i think that i have structured the functions correctly, and everything should work fine, but it doesn't call Random.

```
def Menu():
    name = raw_input("What's your name?\n:")
    print "Hello, %s!\nWeclome to the Guessing Game!" % name
    print "Select an option:"
    print "1- Guess a number between 1-100."
    print "2- Guess a number between 1-1000."
    print "3- Guess a number between 1-10,000."
    print "4- Guess a number between 1-100,000."
    print "5- Exit."
    try:
        selection = raw_input("Enter your selection:")
        if selection == 1:
            Random(100)
        elif selection == 2:
            Random(1000)
        elif selection == 3:
            Random(10000)
        elif selection == 4:
            Random(100000)  
        elif selection == 5:
            exit()
    except:
        os.system("clear")
        print "Sorry, that wasn't an option. Enter your selection again."

Menu()
```

Comment: The answer by @alex.s is fine so I won't write another. A good question to ask *yourself* is how could you have used `print` or the interactive Python shell to find your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input()` retuns a string so you have to cast the input to `int` or compare the input with strings. Either this way:

```
selection = raw_input("Enter your selection:")
if selection == "1":
    Random(100)
elif selection == "2":
    Random(1000)
elif selection == "3":
    Random(10000)
elif selection == "4":
    Random(100000)  
elif selection == "5":
    exit()
```

or this way:

```
selection = raw_input("Enter your selection:")
if int(selection) == 1:
    Random(100)
elif int(selection) == 2:
    Random(1000)
elif int(selection) == 3:
    Random(10000)
elif int(selection) == 4:
    Random(100000)  
elif int(selection) == 5:
    exit()
```

Furthermore you can avoid `try` by kicking out `elif int(selection) == 5:` and using `else:`" instead. So the game will be ended with any other input than 1,2,3 or 4. There will be no possibility to "enter your selection again" after calling `except` in your code anyway because  the script stops.

The function `Random` is not very optimal. See this:

```
    def Random(select): 
        range = "1-" + str(select)
        Correct_Guess = random.randint(1,select+1)
        Difficulty()
```

It is the same but shorte and more readable ;)

Comment: How did i miss that :/ Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Btw, i used continue before in except but it didn't work so i removed all of them, because i wanted a way to ask the user again if they enter something else that's unexpected, but there is no goto in python, and it needs to be structured, so i was trying to used try except.

Comment: Sure :) Btw, i have another weird issue in Difficutlty() it keeps going to else for some reason :/